How to give custom ID Number to vc_column-inner's vc_custom_##### in WPBakery Page Builder
How does one control the Inner Colum styling to target each “vc_custom”
vc_column-inner vc_custom_###########
I do not see any documentation about this. Only way to do so I’ve found through trial and error is CSS (Gear Icon) but if you make changes to the inner column later on, the said vc_custom_### column’s ID number will change.
or is there a way to give the vc_custom_####### a custom name vs auto generated one?

First you have to map your new custom field in the column then in your theme create folder js_composer which allows you to overwrite templates such as vc_column.php where you can add your new custom field and add it to where you want. There are many examples on internet how to map new field and the rest is straight forward.

I was not looking to make customization to the theme structure itself and asking if within WPB documentation there was a better way to give vc_custom of the inner column unique names
